# zend framework where query with regexp

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to search for data within the database with these conditions

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SMS_Reports 
WHERE AWB_NO REGEXP '1500' 
   OR SMS_TEXT REGEXP 'SOME STRING' 
   OR Update_at LIKE '%some string%';
```

I want to query in the database with the above criteria please help me with the query for Zend framework

Comment: `OR WHERE` should only be `OR`

Comment: ok @Qirel done can you please tell me the query for zend

Comment: Use raw query method.. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161370/raw-sql-query-with-zend-framework   most easy way of doing this..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I want to write it with SQL object `$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
        $select = $sql->select(array('t1' => $this->table));`

Comment: Zend does not support MySQL's keyword REGEXP  native -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709016/zf2-mysql-regex-for-whole-word-searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here what I found  and its work for me

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $select = $sql->select(array('t1' => $this->table));
    $select->columns(array(
        'From' => 'SMS_From',
        'AWB_NO',
        'Text' => 'SMS_TEXT',
        'Status',
        'Send_at' => new Expression('IF(t1.Update_at IS NOT NULL,t1.Update_at,"")')
    ));
    if (isset($data['search_string']) && !empty($data['search_string'])) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data['search_string']));
        $select->where(array(
            new PredicateSet(
                array(
                    new PredicateExpression("Update_at = '".$date."'"),
                    new PredicateExpression("SMS_TEXT REGEXP '".$data['search_string']."'"),
                    new PredicateExpression("AWB_NO REGEXP '".$data['search_string']."'"),
                ),
                PredicateSet::COMBINED_BY_OR
            ),
        ));
    }
    $select->join(array('t2' => 'MST_Clients'),'t1.Client_ID = t2.Client_ID',
        array(
            'Client_Name' => new Expression('IF(t2.Client_Name IS NOT NULL,t2.Client_Name,"")'),
        ),'LEFT');
    // echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);die; 
    if($paging) {
        $dbAdapter = new DbSelect($select, $this->getAdapter ());
        $paginator = new Paginator($dbAdapter);
        return $paginator;
    }else {
        $smt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $result = $this->resultSetPrototype->initialize($smt->execute())->toArray();
        return $result;
    }
```